# Correlation of Class Functions

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algorithms

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $f_1,f_2$ be two real-valued class functions of $G$. Assume that multiplying elements of $G$ takes $O(1)$-time.

Let $s:G\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$s(g):=\sum_{x\in G} f_1(x)f_2(g\cdot x).$$

When $G$ is abelian, the maximum of $s$ can be found efficiently using FFT and other similar methods.

For most abelian groups, the complexity of finding the maximum of $s$ and the element of $G$ at which the maximum is attained is $$O(|G| \ln |G|).$$

**Question 1:** Is it true in general that one can beat the naive algorithm of $O(|G|^2)$? What is the most efficient algorithm for a given $G$?

**Question 2:** Is it necessary to require that $f_1,f_2$ are class functions? For abelian $G$'s, this condition degenerates. For non-abelian $G$'s, if one wants to apply representation theory, this looks like a necessary condition. But maybe there are other lines of attack.

More concretely, are there examples of $G$'s for which one can solve the non-restricted problem in asymptotically less than $O(|G|^2)$ operations?

Comment: This paper might interest you: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02445.pdf

Comment: @DrorSpeiser That indeed looks closely related to my problem, thank you.